# Typical arraysegment<byte> stream?

Tags: c#, stream, websocket

I've been googling this thing for quite some time but haven't found a single sample of processing a live ArraySegment stream byte by byte after a

```
while(true)
        {
            WebSocketReceiveResult result = await Conn.ReceiveAsync(readBuffer, token);
```

Could anyone show a sample?

Comment: These are my point of reference when I want to study networking apps: [Kayak](https://github.com/kayak/kayak) and [Firefly](https://github.com/FireflyServer/firefly). But they doesn't use aysnc/await. I've wrote a sample that use async/await for a sample web server, [check it](https://github.com/gsscoder/owinhttplistener) - may be can help.

Comment: Neither of them use Websockets, I do not understand why Microsoft would add such functions with zero documentation

Comment: SignalR does https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR (but don't know if use this specific API) - check it out